# Phishing attack ahead (in Chrome) - my domain got blacklisted, how to get it normal back?

Tags: google-chrome, restore, phishing

Here's what Chrome shows after the programmer was messing around with php script and web site testing and tweaking something.

**Phishing attack ahead
Attackers on packandsell.today might try to trick you to steal your information (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).**

Can you help me please to find a procedure that can get my domain status to normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please go through this: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/99020?hl=en

hope you will have a clear idea and find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Imran.
I as well found this link helpful

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/3cMzRY2Mt_c